# VS code cannot import local python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

All of my project files in VS code suddenly gives an error saying that it cannot import modules (even tho the modules are local i.e same directory and they used to work pretty well before).
The code works fine in pycharm but not in VS code, any idea whats going on?

```
Code:
from backend.util.crypto_hash import crypto_hash
from backend.config import MINE_RATE

error:


env DEBUGPY_LAUNCHER_PORT=34625 /home/nikhil/python-blockchain/blockchain-env/bin/python /home/nikhil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.3.71659/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/no_wheels/debugpy/launcher /home/nikhil/python-blockchain/backend/app/__init__.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nikhil/python-blockchain/backend/app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from backend.blockchain.blockchain import Blockchain
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'
```

Comment: are the modules present in a virtual env?

Comment: @Suyash   I feel so, how can I check?

Comment: type     ''which pip''  (without the quotes)  in the terminal in vscode and tell me the output

Comment: /home/nikhil/python-blockchain/blockchain-env/bin/pip

Comment: ok so you're using a virtual env

Comment: @Suyash I feel if it was related to the modules then it wouldnt work in pycharm or it wouldnt have worked at all (tho it used to work earlier)

Comment: @Suyash Yes Yes, my interpreter is also set to the vir env

Comment: in that case, give me the output of this command: pip list

Comment: atomicwrites (1.3.0)
attrs (19.3.0)
click (7.1.1)
Flask (1.1.1)
importlib-metadata (1.6.0)
itsdangerous (1.1.0)
Jinja2 (2.11.1)
MarkupSafe (1.1.1)
more-itertools (8.2.0)
packaging (20.3)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
pluggy (0.13.1)
py (1.8.1)
pyparsing (2.4.6)
pytest (5.1.2)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.14.0)
wcwidth (0.1.9)
Werkzeug (1.0.1)
zipp (3.1.0)

Comment: @Suyash I am not sure if local modules are supposed to present in the pip list

Comment: if you execute that command outside of an env, it will list the local modules

Comment: Did you use the same virtual environment on PyCharm?

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Hi I just used my system's terminal instead of VS's terminal. I feel something is wrong with the VS terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Close VS Code,
start it again, Go to File > open folder (open your project folder in vs code),
if it gives a prompt to select a existing virtual environment, select that.

Then you should be good to go.

More unrelated information:

I assume the issue here is that there's some problem with VS Code not recognizing the virtual environment properly. This has happened to me several times and I cannot point out why that happens. But the above solution is a quick fix and always works for me.

Comment: I am not getting any prompts when I do that, even without the vir env ir should work since the module is a local one.  I am not sure why it suddenly stopped recognizing the module

Comment: Now I see 2 possibilities: 1) there have been conflicts with another module- in this case i'd suggest you to make a new venv, install all dependancies in it and use it. 2) the module didn't install correctly (rare), so uninstall it and then install it again

Comment: I am getting the same issue but only when using debugpy. 'python -m debugpy --listen 5678 /home/app/src/main.py' gives 'No module named main' where just 'python /home/app/src/main.py' runs as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will resolve OP's (ten-month old) question, but I've been struggling with the same error using debugpy while trying to configure VSCode's debugger.

Step 4 of [this](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/importerror-docker/) resource resolved the issue for me. In particular, I was using the `-m` flag when running debugpy, but the module to be run was not in the current working directory. Once I had changed this, the debugger worked as expected. As an example, if the command was originally:

```
python -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 ./some/directory/my_script.py
```

then the following two commands would rectify it:

```
cd ./some/directory
python -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 ./my_script.py
```

After doing this, I no longer received the "No module found" error.

Answer (score 1):

**The main reason is that VSCode does not automatically configure environment variables for you, but PyCharm does.** The simplest method is adding your module file to system path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(module_file_path)
```

The better solution is to config your environmental path named **PYTHONPATH**, adding related module path to it, and after that you will no longer need import system path manually.

[image]

Hope it works!